# Couldn't upload a manifest in azure management portal

Tags: rest, office365

I am following the post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx to develop an application which needs to access the calendar mail and contact API s . I am able to get an id_token . I generated a self signed certificate and have  the values for $base64Thumbprint, $base64Value and $keyid. But when i make the changes in the manifest and try to upload it shows an error 
"ParameterValidationException=Invalid parameters provided; BadRequestException=One or more properties contains invalid values.;"

```
"keyCredentials": [
{
      "customKeyIdentifier":"tt89GrwSlCRxxUiDfJMW8p29NCU=",
      "keyId":"3b65c351-4869-4a6d-6d6f-5fd53fc2a802",
      "type":"AsymmetricX509Cert",
      "usage":"Verify",
      "value":"MIIDLDCCAhagAwIBAgICBNIQK************j0tSzvQmi7DJR0R5gpvii"// have omitted characters in between 
  }
],
```

may i know where am i going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably not doing anything wrong. I had this error a few times and in my case it seemed somehow related to the editor putting in some invisible character. Maybe you want to try with a different editor. Give it a try and let me know if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Ya it worked when i tried with a different editor thanks Matthias

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Notepad++ which wasn't successful then I tried with Sublime Text, the manifest file got uploaded without any error.